# Re-open the same window with a second click on a link in an email?

Tags: html, email, html-email

This is a rather simple problem but I couldn't find any solution.

We have an email sent out by our web-based application and there are links in the email that open specific pages in the application.

If a user clicks on a link, the browser opens the relevant page. If the user clicks on the same link again, the browser opens another window with the same page. Is there any way I can prevent opening another page and switch back to the first window? Each unique link should open a single page only, even if clicked more than once.

I know this is possible in our web application with the Javascript `window.open()` method by providing a name for the window. Can the same be achieved with an anchor tag? The name attribute for an anchor tag seems to be depreciated - but I don't think that can be used for this.

Sample links in email:

```
<a href="http://example.com/id=1" >ID 1</a><br/>
<a href="http://example.com/id=3" >ID 2</a><br/>
<a href="http://example.com/id=2" >ID 3</a><br/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign the target attribute in the links

```
<a href="http://example.com/id=1" target="test_1">ID 1</a><br/>
<a href="http://example.com/id=3" target="test_2">ID 2</a><br/>
<a href="http://example.com/id=2" target="test_3">ID 3</a><br/>
```

I used test_1, test_2, test_3 - but that can really be anything you want.

Comment: I though target could only have 4 options: _blank, _parent, _self and _top. Isn't naming the target depreciated in HTML5?

Comment: Shouldn't be deprecated, as it is meant to call the framename, but when the framename doesn't exist it opens a new window creating that window with that framename.

Comment: Great! Will use this. Thanks! (This is where I saw it was depreciated: https://html.com/attributes/a-target/ )

Comment: in that page it states: In HTML5 Frames were deprecated; the target values were not, and it just says that _blank is the only relevant target. which is clearly incorrect :)